# authorization for multiple local strategies in passportjs using mongodb and nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, authorization, passport.js, passport-local

I am implementing multiple local strategies for authentication using passportjs and mongodb in nodejs. To achieve authentication, I have used middleware in deserializeUser. Something like this. I have two types of users, one is User and the other is Vendor. Vendors will be selling products and Users will be buying products. 
I have created different schema for vendors and users with different local strategy names. Authentication works fine for me.

```
module.exports = function(passport){

// Passport needs to be able to serialize and deserialize users to support persistent login sessions
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {

    console.log('user id is: ' + user._id);
    done(null, user._id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {


    User.findById(id, function (err, user) {
        if(err)
            done(err);
        if(user) {
            done(null, user);
        }
        else {
            Vendor.findById(id, function (err, user) {
                if(err)
                    done(err);
                done(null, user);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

What I want to do is, the 'User' account should not be able to access pages which is there for vendors and vendors should not be able to access pages, which is there for users. In this way I want to provide access control over the data which is shared by these two types of user account. 
I think it is not possible with passport but we need to write some middle-ware for it. Can we achieve it through some middleware or is there any package in npm which we can use for this purpose. If anyone can give some examples of some simple middleware, it will be really helpful for me.

Comment: why don't you add an attribute to each type of your users and check for that attribute to detect their type?

Comment: Aᴍɪʀ So you mean, in the schema for User, I should add a field like isUser : true; and in the Vendor schema, I should add a field like isVendor : true. and then if its true then only the user can access ? is that what you mean.

Comment: Kind of ... I mean if the attributes are already different, you can use that as well. For example, if a vendor has a `vendor_id` you can check to see if the current user has that or not.

Comment: i got it. Thanks for your prompt suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem, by introducing one field 'isUser' in 'User' schema and 'isVendor' in 'Vendor' schema and kept its type as Boolean. Now, When a user registers as a 'User', then it stores 'isUser' as true and when a 'Vendor' registers, then it stores 'isVendor' as true. We are storing vendor and User in two different schema. 
Now in the route handler, I wrote a middleware, which is something like this.

```
var isVendor = function (req, res, next) {
if (req.user.isVendor === true) {
return next();
}
res.redirect('/vendorlogin');
};

var isUser = function (req, res, next) {

if(req.user.isUser === true) {
return next();
}
res.redirect('/login');
};
```

Now I add this in my route handler's something like this.

```
/**
* Testing the authorization policy using two different local strategy
*/

router.get('/productsvendor', isAuthenticated, isVendor, function      (req, res) {

res.send('this is product vendor page, which should be seen only by vendors');
});

router.get('/itemuser', isAuthenticated, isUser , function (req, res) {

res.send('this is item user page, which should be seen only by users');

});
```